# How to specify all routes except one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to overwrite my old project from native JS to React with MobX. My application has several pages and I want to use react-router to handle them. For that I need to return index.html page for all routes from my Spring-boot controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class RoutesController {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "", "/**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Also I have special folder for static components on embedded Apache Tomcat server. This folder contains build.js for my client-side application. 
Controller presented above can serve all requests to server with index.html page, but I have also client-side application on `/static/**` route. 
How can I specify all routes in my controller except `/static/**`?

Comment: If you use Spring Boot, static resources should be handled by it automatically. Do you have any problems with it?

Comment: @dunni Thanks for the reply! No, I have no problem with static resources. The only problem is that I don't know how to configure the handling of routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. To get only one page for all requests your controller must implement `ErrorController` and two methods: `error` and `getErrorPath`.
Here is an example:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class RoutesController implements ErrorController {
    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "index";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Server get the request and will not find any routes, so it will return result of `error` method.

Maybe that's not the best solution, but after three days of searching the Internet I have not found anything better.